# From a Java Stream of Map group them by keys and find the maxium value not working as expected

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

From an input `Stream<Map<String,Float>` I am trying to find the unique analytes and which has the maxium value. I tried the below but not getting the expected result. 
I am making some mistake in collecting the value.

Sample Input Data: `List<Map<String,Float>`

```
{HNO3=2.005}
{HNO3=2.009}
{HCl=10.2}
{F-=0.0, HNO3=50.0}

Actual result   : {HCl=Optional[HCl=10.2], F-=Optional[F-=0.0], HNO3=Optional[HNO3=50.0]}
Expected result : {HCl=10.2, F-=0.0, HNO3=50.0}
```

Java code I tried:-

```
finalResponse.getChosenStartingMaterials()
    .stream()
    .map(Analyte::getMatrixUtilisationMap)  // Stream<Map<String,Float>>
    .flatMap(it -> it.entrySet().stream())   
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.maxBy((m1, m2) -> m1.getValue().compareTo(m2.getValue()))))
```

Comment: You are getting an `Optional` Object. Just do Optional.get() and collect it ?

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger?

Comment: your original code produces `Map<String, Optional<Map.Entry<String, Float>>>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Collectors.maxBy()` produces an `Optional`, since if `maxBy` is applied on an empty `Stream`, it has to return an empty `Optional`.

You can use `Collectors.toMap` instead of `Collectors.groupingBy` to avoid the `Optional`s:

```
finalResponse.getChosenStartingMaterials()
    .stream()
    .map(Analyte::getMatrixUtilisationMap)  // Stream<Map<String,Float>>
    .flatMap(it -> it.entrySet().stream())   
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                              Map.Entry::getValue,
                              (v1, v2) -> v1.compareTo(v2) >= 0 ? v1 : v2));
```

or

```
finalResponse.getChosenStartingMaterials()
    .stream()
    .map(Analyte::getMatrixUtilisationMap)  // Stream<Map<String,Float>>
    .flatMap(it -> it.entrySet().stream())   
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                              Map.Entry::getValue,
                              Float::max));
```

Comment: would it work with `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        Float::max));` ?